# Intersection of Kernel(T) and Subspace of Domain

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $U$ be a subspace of $V$.
Given a Linear transformation $T : V \to W$ between vector spaces $V$ and $W$ what is $Ker(T) \cap U$ ?

How would we find this? is it $\{0\}$ ?

Comment: It would depend on what $T$ is.  It's the kernel of $T$ restricted to $U$.  It would also depend on $U$.

Comment: It could be anything, since every subspace of $V$ is the kernel of a linear transformation.